# Does function call via @ ignore HoldFirst attribute?

Tags: functions, evaluation, attributes

I was trying to test whether using `func[x,y]` is the same as `func[#,y]&@x`:

```
SetAttributes[test, HoldFirst]
test[1 + 2 - 3, 5 - 5]
test[#, 5 - 5] &@(1 + 2 - 3)
```

> test[1 + 2 - 3, 0]
>
> test[0, 0]

So apparently, `HoldFirst` is ignored in the second case. Why is it so? Is the argument of `@` evaluated before actually being passed?

Comment: `(1 + 2 - 3)` is evaluated before being passed. You can try `test[#, 5 - 5] &@Defer[(1 + 2 - 3)]` to prevent evaluation of `(1 + 2 - 3)`.

Comment: @kglr This isn't correct.  There are many misunderstanding about `Defer`.  The most important thing to remember is that it deal with *formatting* and not evaluation.  It is only useful in a notebook and only if you mean to copy the output or edit it otherwise in a notebook.  In a way it is for user interaction. It is not useful for programming and expression manipulation and has no effect when running the kernel without a front end.  You example is effectively the same as `test[#, 5 - 5] &@HoldForm[(1 + 2 - 3)]`.  The head `HoldForm` or `Defer` stays there it just doesn't print.

Comment: BTW the same applies to `Interpretation`.  It's all about formatting and user interaction within a notebook and has nothing to do with expression manipulation or programming, nor does it have any effect when there is no notebook environment.

Comment: @Szabolcs excellent point; thank you.

Comment: I think you might find the answers to an old question of mine useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494

Answer (score 13, accepted):

andre has given a good answer. I will add a little further clarification. The function `f[#]&` is a different function than the function `f` and does not have its attributes. It is the short form of

```
Function[x, f[x]]
```

Assume

```
Clear[f]; SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
```

has been evaluated. Even though `f` is `HoldFirst`, both

```
Function[x, f[x]][1 + 1]
```

and

```
Function[x, f[x]] @ (1 + 1)
```

give

> `f[2]`

When the pure function is also given the attribute `HoldFirst`, evaluation goes as you expect.

```
Function[x, f[x], HoldFirst] @ (1 + 1)
```

> `f[1 + 1]`

Answer (score 12):

This is intended, but is one of the main premature evaluation case when one works with unevaluated expression.

Particularly `f @ expression` is not equivalent to `f[#]& @ expression`
See :

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[1 + 1]
f[#]& @ (1 + 1)
```

> f[1 + 1]
>   f[2]

but :

```
f @ (1 + 1)
```

> f[1 + 1]

The `@` is not responsible of the premature evaluation. The cause is rather the use of `#&` applied to an expression.

**Edit**

To confirm this, one can try :

```
f[#]& [1 + 1]
```

> f[2]

Answer (score 10):

There are two separate issues here, which you are confusing.

> Does function call via @ ignore HoldFirst attribute?

No, it doesn't.  `f[x]` and `f@x` are different textual representations of the very same expression.  Writing it either way has absolutely no effect on evaluation.  The *parser* converts both into the very same internal representation.  The evaluator works with this internal representation and doesn't know how you wrote the code originally, as `f[x]` or `f@x`.

> I was trying to test whether using `func[x,y]` is the same as `func[#,y]&@x`

This is an entirely different question, and has nothing to do with using the `@` character.  It's about using a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).  Note that `func[#,y]&@x` and `func[#,y]&[x]` are exactly the same thing.  The latter has no `@` in it.

By default, any pure function behaves as if it had no attributes (such as `HoldAll`, etc.).  Demo:

```
Hold[#] &[1 + 1]
(* Hold[2] *)
```

Let's write this using its FullForm:

```
Function[Hold[#]][1 + 1]
```

If you look up [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), you will see that we can construct a funtcion with the same behaviour using the following syntaxes too:

```
Function[x, Hold[x]]
```

or

```
Function[Null, Hold[#]]
```

If we write it this way, we get access to the third argument, where we can specify attributes.  See the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) documentation page for more information.

```
Function[x, Hold[x], HoldAll][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)
```