# An evaluation control problem

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I want to have a function called `printRes[expr_,var_]`, which does the following:

```
x=1;
expr:=a*x^3;

result=printRes[expr,x];
result
(* derivative of a*x^3 relative to x is 3ax^2, and when x=1, result is 3a. *)
```

I am unable to put all this into a row after many tries. How do I do it?

Comment: Like ``StringTemplate["The derivative of `fun` with respect to `var` is `res` when `var` = `val`"]@<|"fun" -> ToString[f, TraditionalForm], "var" -> x, 
  "val" -> 1, "res" -> ToString[D[f, x] /. x -> 1, TraditionalForm]|>``?

Comment: Hi, @J.M. Thanks for mention `StringTemplate`, haven't used it before. But there is a problem, `x=1` must be evaluated before evaluation of `printRes`

Comment: So, what did you see after running the snippet I gave? Note the expression fed to `"res"` in the association.

Comment: @J.M. Your solution seems not give the expected result. I have edited my post to make it more clear

Comment: Well, the trouble is that you assigned `x` to be `1` at the outset.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, that is what I request : ) sorry for my unclear statement before

Answer (score 5):

Localize your `x` using `Block`. Use `LocalizedBlock` [if you want to allow non-symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71883/12) for `x`.

```
ClearAll[printRes]
SetAttributes[printRes, HoldAll]
printRes[expr_, x_] :=
 Internal`LocalizedBlock[{x},
   Print[D[expr, x]]
 ]
```

If you really want to both make use of the value of `x` and ignore it,

```
ClearAll[printRes]
SetAttributes[printRes, HoldAll]
printRes[expr_, x_] :=
 Module[{res},
  Internal`LocalizedBlock[{x},
   res = Hold[Evaluate@D[expr, x]];
  ];
  {res, ReleaseHold[res]}
 ]
```

But I find a function with such behaviour weird and confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much, Szabolcs! I just understand your answer, very neat and clear. upvoted

Comment: A complete solution would be like this : `ClearAll[printRes];
SetAttributes[printRes, HoldAll];
printRes[expr_, x_] := Module[{expr0, res},
  Block[{x}, expr0 = HoldForm@Evaluate@expr; 
   res = HoldForm@Evaluate@D[expr, x];];
  Row[{"derivative of ", expr0, " relative to ", HoldForm@x, " is ", 
    res, ", and when ", HoldForm@x, " = ", x, ", result is ", 
    ReleaseHold[res], "."}]]`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
ClearAll@printRes;
SetAttributes[printRes, HoldAll]
With[{trad = TraditionalForm}, 
 With[{hold = trad@HoldForm@# &}, 
  printRes[expr_, y_] := 
   "derivative of " <> #1 <> " relative to " <> #2 <> " is " <> #3 <> 
      ", and when " <> #2 <> "=" <> #4 <> ", the result is " <> #5 & @@ 
    ToString /@ 
     Block[{y}, {hold@expr, hold@y, hold@D[expr, y], trad@y, trad@D[expr, y]}]]]
```

Comment: Hi, xzczd. Thank you so much. It works! But I just found I missed something important in my post which may bring true difficulty. Take a look at my updated post again. Very sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @matheorem I found a cleaner solution, check my update.

Comment: upvoted! Thank you so much. It is weird that it is failed on my first try. But it seems great now. I need sometime to figure it out : )

Comment: @matheorem Well, this solution has avoided most of the `Hold*` stuff, the key point is the `Block`. We first use `Block` to temporarily localize the variable so `expr`, `D[expr, y]`, etc. will evaluate but not evaluate to a number, then use `HoldForm` to hold those should not evaluate even if they're no longer inside the `Block`. For more information, try `printRes[expr, x] // Trace`.

Comment: I think the truth is more tricky. You used `hold=HoldForm@#&` instead of `hold=HoldForm` makes an essential difference (neglect `TraditionalForm`)

Comment: @matheorem Oh, I forgot to mention that. As to the issue, this is a strongly related post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130889/1871